# Can't click on snippets anymore

Tags: 2sxc

If I want to edit a template in 2SXC, this used to be blazing fast, as I clicked on the snippets available. After upgrading to 8.8, I can not click on the snippets anymore. That is, I can click on them, but the snippet is not added in the template.

Something I missed here? Is this done differently nowadays?

Many thanks.

Tycho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug. Should be fixed in 2sxc 8.9